# How to implement FocalLoss in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

[Focal Loss](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf) is a loss aimed at addressing class imbalance for a classification task.

Here is my attempt

```
class FocalLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            weight=None,
            gamma=2.,
            reduction='none'
    ):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
        self.weight = weight
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.reduction = reduction

    def forward(self, input_tensor, target_tensor):
        log_prob = F.log_softmax(input_tensor, dim=-1)
        prob = torch.exp(log_prob)
        return F.nll_loss(
                ((1 - prob) ** self.gamma) * log_prob,
                target_tensor,
                weight=self.weight,
                reduction=self.reduction
        )
```

Upon `loss.backward()` this gives

```
raise RuntimeError("grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs")
RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

This is the call to the loss function:

```
loss = self._criterion(log_probs, label_batch)
```

When `self._criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` it works, and when `self._criterion = FocalLoss()` it gives the error.

How do I make this loss behave like `CrossEntropyLoss` API-wise?

Comment: AFAIK such errors appear when one attempts to differentiate a function that returns a tensor, as opposed to a scalar. So, probably, your `forward` function returns a tensor

Comment: @ForceBru Please see edit. I just want behavior similar to `CrossEntropyLoss`

Answer (score 0):

reduction='none'

This is the culprit. Look at CrossEntropyLoss and you will see the default is
reduction='mean'. That means that the output of XELoss is a tensor with only one element in it; [1, 2] turns to [1.5]. You can't call .backward() as-is on a tensor with more than one element in it. I suggest changing this to 'mean' as in XELoss.

The idea behind this is that .backward() calculates the gradient of some number. So if you have "2x" and call backward(), the gradient with respect to 2 is x, and the gradient with respect to x is 2. On the other hand, if you had x * [1, 2] and you call backward, it's not really proper to calculate the gradient of a vector; instead you would calculate the Jacobian.